# Python: is there a way to force code to ignore a variable if user input is only whitespace?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first time posting and I haven't been learning to code for very long. This is the first script I've tried to build on my own, please be nice.

The program is linked to a CSV of elements and their atomic mass. The user inputs a chemical formula and the return is the molecular mass and a breakdown of the molecular mass percentage. It runs fine but as it  stands it **requires** 6 values, eg H 2 S 1 O 4 for H2SO4. Obviously I want to have the option for long formulae but for shorter ones the script returns an error saying it expected 6 variables but only had 4 to unpack eg: H2O1.

Is there a straightforward way to make the script skip/ignore variables if there is no user input/the input is only white-space? I've been Googling it but either it's more difficult than I imagine or I'm not using the search engine well enough. I messed around with for loops but couldn't get anything to play ball.

Attached is the code, I'm aware that it could probably be twice as simple/slick if I had a little more knowledge. Thanks in advance.

```
def formula():
element_1, element_1_size, element_2, element_2_size, element_3, element_3_size = input("Enter your formula: ").split()

element_1_mass = float(elements_data_symbols.loc[element_1, "Atomic Mass"])
element_2_mass = float(elements_data_symbols.loc[element_2, "Atomic Mass"])
element_3_mass = float(elements_data_symbols.loc[element_3, "Atomic Mass"])

element_1_molecular_mass = element_1_mass * int(element_1_size)
element_2_molecular_mass = element_2_mass * int(element_2_size)
element_3_molecular_mass = element_3_mass * int(element_3_size)

molecular_mass = element_1_molecular_mass + element_2_molecular_mass + element_3_molecular_mass

molecule_name = str(element_1 + element_1_size + element_2 + element_2_size + element_3 + element_3_size)

print("Molecular mass of " + molecule_name + ": " + str(molecular_mass) + " g/mol")

element_1_percentage = element_1_molecular_mass / molecular_mass * 100
element_2_percentage = element_2_molecular_mass / molecular_mass * 100
element_3_percentage = element_3_molecular_mass / molecular_mass * 100


print(element_1 + ": " + str(element_1_percentage) + " %")
print(element_2 + ": " + str(element_2_percentage) + " %")
print(element_3 + ": " + str(element_3_percentage) + " %")
print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right a more efficient way of doing this would be using a loop to go through each pair of elements within the array, but keeping it simple you could amend your code to conditionally set elements only if the input array is at a certain length:

```
    # Receive user input as an array
    elements = input("Enter your formula").split()

    # First element should always exist (but could also do this conditionally)
    element_1 = elements[0]
    element_1_size = elements[1]

    # Check if array has at least 4 elements
    if len(elements) >= 4:
        element_2 = elements[2]
        element_2_size = elements[3]

    # Check if array has at leat 6 elements
    if len(elements) >= 6:
        element_3 = elements[4]
        element_3_size = elements[5]
```

Comment: consider object oriented ways of solving such problems. Checking limit is fine here, but it cannot extend dynamically for various inputs.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that? I don't mean an OO answer to my issue unless you think it would help. Do you mean breaking the problem down and writing a function to get around it? Sorry if I sound like a bumbling idiot.